# How to echo output and append to another file using PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to echo the output and append to an existing file using php. But I'm getting error. The out is good on the screen if I remove " >> master_yml.html" from the scrip. Please advice. Thanks

```
 <?php

 $filename = './workspace/vars1.txt';
 $contents = file($filename);

 foreach($contents as $line) {

         echo "<TR><TD>$line:</TD><TD> <input type=\"text\"name=\"$line\"size=\"30\" value= $line ></TD> </TR> " >> master_yml.html ;
  }

  ?>
```

Comment: This isn't `bash`. You don't have output redirection (`>>`). Instead, you'd need to use [`file_put_contents`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) or [a combination of `fopen` and `fwrite`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php).

Comment: Can you assit with an example? thx

Comment: Just... `echo` the string, then `fwrite` the same string to the file? I provided links to the documentation.

Comment: I added fwrite but it still not working. Please advise. thx

<?php

$filename = './workspace/vars1.txt';
$contents = file($filename);

foreach($contents as $line) {
   $text = echo "<TR><TD>$line:</TD><TD> <input type=\"text\" name=\"$line\"size=\"30\" value= $line ></TD> </TR> ";
$fp = fopen('master_yml.html', 'w');
fwrite($fh , $test );
fclose($fn)
}

?>

Comment: Well, you've named your file resource three different things. `$fp`, `$fh`, or `$fn` - which is it? Also, you should probably call `fopen` before you loop, and `fclose` after the loop is complete. Finally, use the `a` mode for `fopen` to append, unless you want to overwrite the file every time the script runs.

Comment: I fixed the $fp and change the order of the fopen of the loop but it still not working. Please advise. many thanks.

<?php

$filename = './workspace/vars1.txt';
$contents = file($filename);
$fp = fopen('master_yml.html', 'a');
foreach($contents as $line) {
  $test = echo "<TR><TD>$line:</TD><TD> <input type=\"text\" name=\"$line\"size=\"30\" value= $line ></TD> </TR> ";
fwrite($fp , $text );
fclose($fp);
}

?>

Comment: While I don't like outright writing code for people, take a look at the answer I posted. You can't assign a variable to `echo "some string"` - echo has no return value. You'd have to construct the string, `echo` it, **then** `fwrite` it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [combination of `fopen()` and `fwrite()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php).

For your example:

```
<?php

$filename = './workspace/vars1.txt';
$contents = file($filename);
$file = fopen('master_yml.html', 'a');

foreach ($contents as $line) {
    $str = "<TR><TD>$line:</TD><TD> <input type=\"text\"name=\"$line\"size=\"30\" value= $line ></TD> </TR> ";
    echo $str;
    fwrite($file, $str);
}

fclose($file);
```

Comment: Yes, I did not assign the string. However, that fixed the problem. thanks a million.